# Apply multiple commands to messages in mutt

Tags: mutt

I created a macro in mutt to send the selected message to my archive folder:

> `macro index,pager ,m s=Archive`

In many cases, new messages are archived right away, so I tried to extend the macro:

> `macro index,pager ,m Wnks=Archive`

This works fine unless the last message is selected. In this case, the target message remains selected after clearing the N/O flag, and the k command moves the selection to the previous message in the list. Is there any way to apply multiple commands to a certain message, without having to resort to movement commands?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mutt normally advances the cursor to the next message whenever a command that modifies the current message is executed. This behavior is controlled by the ['resolve'](http://www.mutt.org/doc/manual/manual-6.html#resolve) configuration variable. So, one solution would be to extend your macro to unset `resolve` before executing the other commands, then re-set it afterwards.

```
macro index,pager ,m ": unset resolve\nWnks=Archive\n: set resolve\n"
```

Note that that is untested. I put it together from your macro plus some macros in my muttrc in which I unset/set various configuration variables before/after executing the core of the macros. Also note the space after each colon. This prevents the following command from being saving in the command-line history. This is not important but can be convenient to avoid clutter in your history.

Comment: Excellent, I removed the "k" from your above solution (it is not required if the message focus does not change). Thanks!